# Type of Products to Achieve This?

Tags: configurable-product, magento-2.1.3, grouped-products

Will be as simple as possible coz it's driving me crazy:

**Clothing Store**

I want 3 PRODUCTS with Color and Size Options one of them is a full outfit

1. Top   Qty: 2
2. Jacket Qty: 2
3. Top & Jacket Qty:2

What type of products I need so if someone bought number 1 then updated stock:

1. Top   Qty: 1
2. Jacket Qty: 2
3. Top & Jacket Qty:1

If someone bought number 3 then

1. Top   Qty: 1
2. Jacket Qty: 1
3. Top & Jacket Qty:1

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Managed to finally do it...

Bought the itoris plugin
Now I can have 1 grouped product associated with configurable products..

This should be a default function from magento hopefully one day